# What is the closest C++ analogue to Ruby's Rack?

Tags: c++, ruby, interface, webserver, rack

I'm a big fan of [Rack](http://rack.github.com/), and I've used it to build several lightweight web apps over the past few years.  I've been curious for a while if something similar exists for C++.  I've spent quite a bit of time searching Google and come up empty-handed.  It doesn't help that I find Rack hard to describe.  Its tagline is "A Ruby Webserver Interface".  Searching for {c++ "webserver interface"}, I've found things that do much more than I want, like [wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), and I've found suggestions to use FastCGI directly.  I feel like Rack fits squarely between these two options.

I'm not sure if I'm having trouble finding a C++ analogue to Rack because no such thing exists or because I'm just using poor search terms.

Is there a close C++ analogue to Rack?  If not, is there a library or small set of libraries that can do most of the lower-level, error-prone stuff for me, but still leave me with the level of control that Rack does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the best options I've found so far:

- [cpp-net-lib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/latest/index.html)  (Thanks @Managu) - This appears to be close to what I had in mind.
- [fastcgi++](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/) - This appears to offers lots of niceties over straight FastCGI without turning into a full framework -- so also close to what I had in mind.
- [Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/) - [According to Zed](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2542135), "Mongrel2's protocol also tends to remove the need for any 'middleware' like WSGI or Rack since its protocol is already similar to what those do."  This comes from a very different angle, but also looks like it satisfies my general criteria.

Answer (score 6):

You might take a look at [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/latest/index.html#).  It gives a fairly low level view of http (both client and server side), but high enough that you aren't constantly dealing with lowest level networking apis.

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct port of Rack, called (obviously ;-) ) Crack. I can't find it at the moment, though, and searching for `c++ crack` is pretty much useless.

Comment: Note: that might have been for C, not C++.

Comment: I can't find it, despite quite a few attempted search phrases.  Thanks for the tip, though.